# User canceling advertisements

Tags: android, admob

Hey I was just curious as to whether or not there was something built into the admob library or another advertisement type where I can set the adview to "cancel-able" and have a supported button pop into it? currently I just have my adview in a relative layout with a small picture overlaying it that has an onClickListener which then animates out and destroys the advertisement. However, ideally, the built in button would register the user interaction but I think that's asking for a little too much...

Thanks in advance!
Regards,
-Pete

here is my current "ad-layout"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#959595"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ad_Layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/adView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/adView" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/adView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/adView"
    android:src="@drawable/cancelbutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your question is a bit unclear to me, can you elaborate any?

Comment: above is the code I use to get a cancel button on an advertisement but placing a listener on the image view so the user can click it and initiate the animate out sequence. however, I would prefer it if there were a more professional way to do this hopefully built into the library which I just missed?

Comment: This is not currently an option in the AdMob library.